# GridBagLayout not working as I wish

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Could you hava a look at [this picture.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11I7ZXEazPZ1nlZTdKy8Anfk90q8ega1APHkHqdk_GsM/edit?usp=sharing)
I've expressed what I want and what I've got.

This is some excerpt from my code:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    commonPanel.add(new Panel(new GridBagLayout()), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    commonPanel.add(new Panel(new GridBagLayout()), c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    commonPanel.add(new Panel(new GridBagLayout()), c);
```

By the way, I understand almost nothing.
My reasoning is:

1. I setup `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` 
   Then all the space should be divided between all the panels both hirizontally and vertically.
2. `c.weightx = 0.5;` is taken from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). They divide the horizontal space between three buttons and for some reasons use weights 0.5 for all the three buttons. Well, let's do the same though it is a mystery why it should be 0.5.
3. `c.weighty = 1.0;` should occupy all the space vetically.

Well, not working. Could you clarify what I'm doing wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your code snippet. It works fine for me. So the problem should be with your "commonPanel". What I did was, I add this "commonPanel" to the content pane by setting GridBagConstaints as well.

```
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints x = new GridBagConstraints();
    x.weightx = 1.0;
    x.weighty = 1.0;
    x.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    JPanel commonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(commonPanel, x);
```

As I realized, you should change the code related to your commonPanel.